# How can I render content of 1 child from ContentChildren QueryList in Angular2+

Tags: angular, angular-template

I would like to render content from one element in QueryList filled by  `ContentChildren`.

Let's say I want to build tab component and this is my template for using such component:

```html
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab title="title1">some content 1<my-tab>
  <my-tab title="title2">some content 2<my-tab>
</my-tabs>
```

My current tabs component html:

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li> *ngFor="let tab of tabs, let i = index; let isLast = last">...<li>
  </ul>        
</div>
<!-- Missing !!! -->
```

Code:

```js
@ContentChildren(MyTabComponent) public tabs: QueryList<MyTabComponent>;
```

My problem is how can I render only active tab? (`<!-- Missing !!! -->`)

I tried:

```html
<ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="tabs.toArray()[currentIndex].content"></ng-container>

<ng-container [ngTemplatetOutlet]="tabs.toArray()[currentIndex].content"></ng-container>    

<ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="tabs.toArray()[currentIndex]"></ng-container>

<ng-container [ngTemplatetOutlet]="tabs.toArray()[currentIndex]"></ng-container>
```

But tab content is never rendered. `my-tab` component html is just:

```html
<div>body</div>
<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

at the moment.

I check online how others are solving this problems, but everyone are using just `<ng-content></ng-content>` and then hides inactive tabs.
But I think better would be to render only needed content (better performance).

I also found [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/stepper/stepper-vertical.html) code where `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></ng-container>` is used, but I tried this approach and it doesn't render anything.

**Edited:**
I also prepare [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hyjkn?file=app%2Fstepper.ts).

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Great idea and [done](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hyjkn?file=app%2Fstepper.ts). Not sure how I couldn't think this myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) inside your `StepComponent` for storing element (in your case `ng-template`):

```typescript
@Component({
    selector: "my-step",
    template: "<ng-template #innerTemplate><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>",
})
export class StepComponent 
{
    @Input()
    public title;

    @ViewChild('innerTemplate') 
    public innerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

And set `ngTemplateOutlet` to that property in `StepperComponent`:

```html
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.innerTemplate"></ng-template>
```

Here is the  forked [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-959kdu?file=app/stepper.ts).

Comment: Would have been nice to use the main example above. Also, in the parent I needed to use ng-content instead of ng-template to see something. `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.innerTemplate"></ng-container>`. Thank you for providing this answer, I was already searching for a bit!

Comment: Thats very confusing if you provide a different example. Could you change this solution to use tab and not step so that we all dont need to figure out what goes where?